# Parsing values based on dependent column with delimiter in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, parsing, dataframe

In example Pandas dataframe below, `Col2` has values for parameters in `Col1`. For example, value of `c` is 2 in row1 and is 7 in row2. Is it possible to extract the value of `c` from this dataframe in Pandas?

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a:b:c:d', 'a:b:x:y:c:d'],
             'col2': ['0:1:2:3', '3:4:5:6:7:8']})
```

[image]

**Expected output:**

```
pd.Series([2,7], name='c')
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @kasi - added expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def f(x):
    p = dict(zip(x['col1'].split(":"),x['col2'].split(":")))
    return p['c']

df.apply(f,axis=1).astype(int).rename('c')
```

Or if you want to lambda:

```
df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['col1'].split(":"),x['col2'].split(":")))['c'],axis=1).astype(int).rename('c')
```

Output:

```
0    2
1    7
Name: c, dtype: int32
```